# How to make QPlainTextEdit width match the width of the widget inside a QTabWidget?

Tags: python, pyside

I have a QTabWidget and a QPlainTextEdit inside a QVBoxLayout.

How can I make the text box the same width as the widget inside the tab, rather than the width of the entire QTabWidget object? In the following picture, I want to remove the small portion that extends past the tab page on the left side.

Basic code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
class test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(test,self).__init__(parent)
        VLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        tabs = QTabWidget()
        line = QLineEdit()
        tabs.addTab(line,"Tab")

        tabs.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.West)
        textBox = QPlainTextEdit()

        VLayout.addWidget(tabs)
        VLayout.addWidget(textBox)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = test()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit( ret )
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your code so we can diagnose the problem

Comment: @nathancy It's very simple code. I've added it.

Comment: @Shock-o-lot QLineEdit or QPlainTextEdit?

Comment: @eyllanesc The second widget in the vertical layout is QPlainTextEdit

Comment: @Shock-o-lot In the title you indicate: *How to make **QLineEdit** width match the width of the widget inside a QTabWidget?* but from the content of your publication I deduce that you want the width of the QPlainTextEdit to change, am I correct? Is the title of your question correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc Oops, It should have been QPlainTextEdit in the title. I've changed it.

Comment: @Shock-o-lot I recommend: 1) Take the time to create a good question, and the title is an important part of it. 2) Always provide an MRE even if it is [*simple code*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418866/how-to-make-qplaintextedit-width-match-the-width-of-the-widget-inside-a-qtabwidg#comment105025020_59418866)

Comment: @eyllanesc Noted. I have found a solution by using a horizontal spacer.

Comment: @Shock-o-lot And how do you match a spacer? Do you calculate the width of the spacer empirically or do you use any function that is the width of the tabbar? If you do it empirically then it is not portable since that value can change depending on the style

Comment: @eyllanesc I am setting the width of the spacer to the height of the tab, retrieved by tabs.tabBar().geometry().height()

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS and the margin property :

```
mainWin.setStyleSheet("QPlainTextEdit { margin-left: 16px; }")
```

I hope it will help you !